# gcc: error: request for member ‘rlen’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, gcc-warning

I have a unsigned char pointer which contains a structure.Now I want to do the following

```
unsigned char *buffer ;

//code to fill the buffer with the relavent information.

int len = ntohs((record_t*)buffer->len);
```

where record_t structure contains a field called len.I am not able to do so and am getting the error.

```
error: request for member ‘len’ in something not a structure or union.
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that the standard reserves names ending with `_t` for future use.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [compilation error: request for member in something not a structure or union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384581/compilation-error-request-for-member-in-something-not-a-structure-or-union) since unary `*` has the same precedence as a cast. Always Google your error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're confident that you're doing the right thing (though this looks very hackish), you just have to get the operator precedence right:

```
ntohs( ((record_t*)buffer)->len );
```

Comment: I have tried the below statement.                   ntohs(((record_t*)buffer)->len); with the parentheses at the right places.but that gives an error  error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules. I may need to mention that buffer is uint8_t buffer[24];

Comment: I did try len only.that was a typo :)

Comment: That's not an error, that's a warning. As I said, you're doing something very hackish and better understand the situation full well. I can only help with the operator precedence, if you don't want to post your actual problem.

Comment: got around the problem by declaring a record_t *rec; rec = (record_t*)buffer; and then doing rec->rlen.I can't figure out why it wouldn't work directly.

Comment: Post it as a separate question if you're curious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630150/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules  have posted a separate question

Answer (score 5):

in `C` you can't just take `buffer->len`, because it's being parsed as if the final result `buffer->len` is being cast to a `record_t *`.  Try

```
((record_t *)buffer)->len
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the reason for this is that `->` has higher precedence than casting, and that the OP should learn the C operator precedence table, or use more parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Try `((record_t*)buffer)->len`

You're casting `buffer->len` to a `record_t*,` when what you want to do is cast `buffer` to a `record_t` and then get the `len` value of that.

Answer (score 2):

Precedence of -> is higher than the cast. Add some parentheses appropriately.